# Use recursion in LaTeX3

Tags: expl3

I want to use recursion to calculate n! in LaTeX3, but found that the result is not correct, mwe is as follows

```latex
\documentclass{article}                          
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set:Nn \froac:n {
\int_compare:nNnTF{#1}={0}{1}
{
     \int_eval:n{#1*\froac:n{#1-1}}
}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\froac:n{4}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

thank you!

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: As things break after you pass single digits, you need include paranethisis around the `#1` things work: `\int_eval:n{(#1)*\froac:n{#1-1}}`.

Comment: I understand, thanks for your answer!

Comment: `l3fp` supports a factorial function `fact`: `\fp_eval:n { fact( ⟨fpexpr⟩ ) }`. It works for integers between 0 and 3248.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ - How many significant digits does the `fact` routine of the `l3fp` package possess?

Comment: @Mico "Normal floating point numbers are stored in base 10, with up to 16 significant figures." according to `texdoc interface3` (2021-11-22), sec. 28.9.1 "Input of floating point numbers"

Answer (score 23):

Remember that TeX is a macro language. Let's manually expand two steps of your recursion to see what's going on:

You started with

```
\froac:n{4}
```

Since 4 is not 0, this becomes

```
\int_eval:n{4*\froac:n{4-1}}
```

Now `4-1` is still not `0`, so the next iteration step results in

```
\int_eval:n{4*\int_eval:n{4-1*\froac:n{4-1-1}}}
```

Of course `4-1*\froac:n{4-1-1}` is not actually what you want. You can fix this by adding parentheses:

```
\documentclass{article}                          
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set:Nn \froac:n {
\int_compare:nNnTF{#1}={0}{1}
{
     \int_eval:n{(#1)*\froac:n{(#1)-1}}
}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\froac:n{4}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Comment: I understand, thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 14):

Just for the sake of variety, here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution.

[image]

The `froac` function produces an overflow for `n>20`. While `n>20` may seem to be a rather poor overflow threshold, do observe that the `\froac:n` macros in (a) @MarcelKrüger's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/625324/5001) and (b) @UlrichDiez's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/625374/5001) both have a far more stringent overflow threshold: `n>12`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\directlua{ 
   %% Define a Lua function called 'froac'
```

```lua
   function froac ( n )
      if n==0 or n==1 then return 1 
      else return n * froac ( n-1 )
      end
   end
```

```tex
}
%% Define a LaTeX wrapper macro called '\froac'
\newcommand\froac[1]{\directlua{tex.sprint(froac(#1))}}

\begin{document}

$\begin{array}{rr}
\directlua { for i = 0 , 20 do 
                tex.sprint ( i .. "&" .. froac ( i ) .. "\\\\" )  
             end }
\end{array}$

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum/Remark*: Even though the usual, i.e., recursive, definition of the factorial function *counts down* from `n` to `0` (or `1`), it is actually more efficient, computationally speaking, to *count up* to `n`. Doing so allows us to evaluate the `if n==0` condition just once at the start of the routine, and then to perform a deterministic `for` loop over a range of integers. In Lua, this idea might be implemented as follows:

```lua
-- Define 'froac' by counting _up_ rather than down
function froac(n)
   if n==0 or n==1 then return 1 
   else f=2; for i=3,n do f=f*i end; return f 
   end
end
```

Answer (score 6):

`\bigintcalcFac` of the package [bigintcalc](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/bigintcalc) can calcuclate factorials of numbers larger than 12, but that is not expl3. ;-)

expl3's `\fp_eval:n { fact( <number> ) }` is preferable because it is considerably faster and the handling of arithmetic overflow is much better.

Accumulating nested calls to `\int_eval` and tokens belonging to these calls by recursively calling `\froac` might trigger a TeX-capacity exceeded error. This is not of real importance here because one also faces the problem of arithmetic overflow.

Nonetheless for the sake of having fun playing with expansion in expl3 the following variant does not accumulate nested calls to `\int_eval`.
But it requires `\exp_args:Nff` which was introduced in 2018-05-15.
And you get an arithmetic-overflow when attempting to calculate the factorial of a number larger than 12. (Same as with `\number\numexpr 1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9*10*11*12\relax` versus `\number\numexpr 1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9*10*11*12*13\relax`.)

```latex
\documentclass{article}                          
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set:Nn \froac:n {
  \exp:w \int_compare:nNnTF{#1}>{1}{\exp_args:Nf\froacstep:nn{\int_eval:n{#1}}{#1}}{\exp_end: 1}
}
\cs_set:Nn\froacstep:nn{
   % #1 result calculated so far
   % #2 factor in the previous iteration
   \int_compare:nNnTF{#2}>{2}{
     \exp_args:Nff\froacstep:nn
                  {\int_eval:n{(#1)*((#2)-1)}}
                  {\int_eval:n{(#2)-1}}
   }{ \exp_end: #1 }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\froac:n{12}\par
\froac:n{5}\par
\froac:n{4}\par
\froac:n{3}\par
\froac:n{2}\par
\froac:n{1}\par
\froac:n{0}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. If I interpret this solution correctly, your variant of the `\froac` macro produces an overflow for `n>12` -- same as in @MarcelKrüger's [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/625324/5001). Is this interpretation/conclusion correct?

Comment: @Mico Yes. Same as with `\number\numexpr1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9*10*11*12\relax` versus `\number\numexpr1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9*10*11*12*13\relax`.

Comment: We do have some bigint code but to-date it's not in the release version

Comment: @JosephWright To what extent is the feature of doing big number arithmetic directly in TeX needed at all? I think a task like calculating factorials of large numbers in TeX at best is a nice "academic exercise". But in everyday practice one should use the tools appropriate to the task. For more complicated calculations there are computer algebra systems which can be called via `\write18/`\shellescape` on the console and which can deliver output to text-files that can be read by TeX...

Comment: @UlrichDiez The obvious ones are (1) bitset operations beyond 32 bits (2) handling arbitrary user input manipulation. I have to worry about the latter for `siunitx`, but do that manually. Thus-far we think we can get away without a full setup for the first case, but Hekio did write his `biginitcalc` code largely to support `bitset`, so we may be wrong.

Answer (score 5):

A different approach, going up with the multiplications:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\factorial}{m}
 {
  \lijunguo_factorial:n { #1 }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \lijunguo_factorial:n
 {
  \fp_eval:n { 1 \int_step_function:nnN { 2 } { #1 } \__lijunguo_multiply:n }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \__lijunguo_multiply:n { *#1 }

% to print long factorials we add tiny breakable space between digits
\NewDocumentCommand{\longfactorial}{m}
 {
  \tl_map_inline:en { \lijunguo_factorial:n { #1 } } { ##1\hspace{0pt plus 0.1pt} }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_map_inline:nn { e }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\factorial{0}

\factorial{1}

\factorial{4}

\factorial{32}

\longfactorial{100}

\end{document}
```

The `\int_step_function:nnN` function will produce `*2*3*…` in “one swoop” so `\fp_eval:n` will compute the whole product (in quite an efficient way). I also add a way to print long results that wouldn't fit a line (this cannot be expandable, though.

[image]

You might also be interested in a shorter version: large factorials will end with many zeros, so we can group them. If you add

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\shortenlongfactorial}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \lijunguo_factorial:n { #1 } }
  \tl_set_eq:NN \l_tmpb_tl \l_tmpa_tl
  \regex_replace_once:nnN { 0* \Z } { } \l_tmpa_tl
  $
   \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
   \times
   10^{\int_eval:n { \tl_count:N \l_tmpb_tl - \tl_count:N \l_tmpa_tl } }
  $
 }
```

that will strip off a sequence of zeros delimited by the end of the token list and then print 10 with the exponent computed by comparing the length of the factorial and the stripped off version.

The document body

```
\begin{document}

\factorial{0}

\factorial{1}

\factorial{4}

\factorial{32}

\longfactorial{100}

\shortenlongfactorial{32}

\shortenlongfactorial{100}

\shortenlongfactorial{200}

\end{document}
```

will output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a factorial function written with [`functional`](https://ctan.org/pkg/functional) package. It is not the shortest answer, but it is very intuitive since this package emulates functional programming in `Lua` language. The evaluation of functions is from inside to outside.

```lua
-- lua code for comparison --
-- define a function --
function Fact (n)
  if n == 0 then
    return 1
  else
    return n * Fact(n-1)
  end
end
-- use the function --
print(Fact(4))
```

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{functional}
\Functional{scoping=true} % make every function become a group
\begin{document}

\IgnoreSpacesOn
\PrgNewFunction \Fact { m } {
  \IntCompareTF {#1} = {0} {
    \Result {1}
  }{
    \Result {\IntMathMult{#1}{\Fact{\IntEval{#1-1}}}}
  }
}
\IgnoreSpacesOff
\Fact{4}

\end{document}
```

Note that with this package, you need to pass return values of functions with `\Result` command.